# Update application installed through InstallShield

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, installshield, updating

So I deployed an application using InstallShield as my installer and after every version I have to uninstall the previous version and install the next version, is there any better way of doing this (updating the application without uninstalling the previous version)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating an existing installation works in InstallShield. Which version you are using?
See the included InstallShield help for the ProductCode, PackageCode and UpgradeCode GUID's. There is a detailed explanation, how it works.

**Overview for small updates/minor upgrades**

For small updates or minor upgrades, the ProductCode in your ISM file remains stable. So, if you execute your setup, the installer looks for an already existing product with that ProductCode.

If not found, it installs the product.

If found, it compares the PackageCodes. If they are equal, it starts the setup in maintenance mode, where you can repair, modify or remove your current installation. If the PackageCodes are not equal, an update of your current installation is provided.

For every change in your setup project you should change the PackageCode.

So, if you change your setup a little bit, create a new PackageCode on the *Installation Information/General Information* page, increase the ProductVersion and rebuild the setup. Then an update is provided.